# How combine build type and flavor to get a build variant debug<Flavor>

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to combine build type and flavor to get build variant such that resources would be taken from most specific res folder?

Lets say I have
`src/main`
`src/debug`
`src/flavor1`
`src/flavor2`

In my `src/main` I have basic configuration.
In my `src/flavor1` and `src/flavor2` I have specific configurations and I want them to be overridden by values from `src/debug`. But flavor values are more specific and `src/debug` config is ignored.

For example each flavor has `@string/app_name`. I.e. `Flavor 1 App`. I want to override `@string/app_name` with `Flavor 1 App Dev`

Is there any way to get effect I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these folders

```
main
  java
  res
flavor1
  java
  res
flavor1Debug
  java
  res
flavor1Release
  java
  res
flavor2
  java
  res
flavor2Debug
  java
  res
flavor2Release
  java
  res
```

Comment: Huh... I really tried that, but it didn't worked first time... And now it works :)